# Julia:How to deal with precision exactness in floating points

Tags: floating-point, julia, precision

I have encountered the case of inexactness in the precision of floating point numbers. As I show below as a simplified version of my code, I compute a sum in equivalent scenarios and in the very last decimals I get different values. This is related to [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

I was wondering if there is any way to resolve this, for example some sort of truncation?

```
s1 = zero(Float64)
s = zero(Float64)
for a in 1:10000
    for k in 1:4
        temp=log(1e-5)
        s1+=temp
        s +=temp
    end
end
s2 = zero(Float64)
for a in 1:10000
    for k in 1:4
        temp = log(1e-5)
        s2+=temp
        s+=temp
    end
end

s1+s2 == s     ###FALSE
s < s1+s2      ###TRUE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: use `≈`(\approx) instead of `=`?  `s1 + s2 ≈ s  #=> true`

Comment: Not a duplicate: this is about strategies to resolve the floating point issue in a particular language, not about why it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point addition is not [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property): changing the order in which you do the addition can give subtly different results due to intermediate rounding.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Use a more accurate summation algorithm, such as [Kahan compensated summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). This is available in Julia as `sum_kbn`:

`julia> sum_kbn(log(1e-5) for a = 1:10000, k = 1:4)
-460517.01859880914`

2. Check for approximate equality instead of exact equality. As mentioned by Gnimuc, you can use `isapprox` (which is also available via the infix `≈`). This accepts `atol` and `rtol` optional arguments for specifying the absolute and relative tolerances, respectively.

`s1+s2 ≈ s`

Answer (score 2):

A Float64 represents a number in the IEEE 754 format. Out of the 64 bit the mantissa occupies 52 bits. This means a precision of about 15 decimal digits.

After your first loop, `s1` and `s` should be the same.

The difference happens in the second loop body. The number in `temp` is always the same. `s` is nearly `temp * 40000.0` when entering the first time the loop body of the second loop. When adding `temp` to `s` this causes to loose the last 4.5 digits of `temp`. This is the cause of the differences since `s2` will be zero and adding `temp` will use all digits of `temp`.

by the way, none of `s,s1+s2` will be (programmatically) the same as `temp * 80000.0` (mathematically all 3 numbers should be the same)

So for reducing numeric errors obey the rules

- prefer multiplications, they retain precision
- adding numbers are more precise the more they are equal. You loose precision in the order of `a / b` (while `a = abs(A), b = abs(B), a > b, b != 0`)
- subtracting numbers looses precision the more they are equal. You loose the precision in the order of leading common digits, or more exactly bits.

This all is no specific problem of julia, it will happen in all languages which using IEEE 754 (C/C++ double, Java double, Julia Float64,..)

```
s1 = zero(Float64)
s = zero(Float64)
for a in 1:40000
    temp=log(1e-5)
    s1+=temp
    s +=temp 
end
s2 = zero(Float64)
for a in 1:40000
    temp = log(1e-5)
    s2+=temp
    s+=temp
end

sm = 80000.0 * log(1e-5);
println(s1+s2 == s)
println(s < s1+s2)
println(s == sm)
println(s1+s2 == sm)

println(s1+s2)
println(sm)
println(s)
```

outputs

```
false
true
false
false
-921034.0371971375
-921034.0371976183
-921034.0371986133
```